# Adding language attribute to homepage

Tags: homepage, multi-language

I have a language plugin that allows me to switch between Dutch (default language) and English. When I select English, an extra attribute is added to the URL: `/?lang=en`.

Now I'm trying to set English as my default language and want the user to automatically be directed to `www.domain.com/?lang=en` instead of just `www.domain.com`.

When I go to `Settings>General` and set the WordPress URL with that extra attribute, the website fails completely. I have also tried by adding editing the `wp.config` file and `htaccess` files, but nothing seems to work.

Website: twd-support.com

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be better aimed at plugin's developers. While I could probably come up with a way to redirect in that way there is no guarantee it wouldn't lock up your site in endless loop or something like that.

Comment: @Rarst, I always got stuck there too :( plugin developer is charging me 150$ ... (said it would take 3 days work, which is bs in my eyes)

Comment: @CustomX, I think you are missing the point here, when a plugin developer does that, he needs the feature to work not just in your specific install and case, but rather with all of his installations. $150 does not sound that much to me for implementing such a feature. (Not that I was able to find such a correspondence). Feel free to implement it by yourself, and if you wish - push your code upstream. I suggest looking at the language detection feature already in the plugin and modifying it.

Comment: @oferwald, there really is no other way in Wordpress to say that is your default page, without being stuck in an infinite loop? Blimey ...

Comment: @CustomX There are a few ways:
1. redirect to another page, save a session cookie to avoid future redirect
2. modify the content of the page itself